# What are the tool kits used for making designs like those on dribble

Tags: tools, open-source, minimalistic

I saw some jaw-dropping designs at [Dribble](http://dribbble.com/) and [Behance](http://www.behance.net/).

Can someone give the idea about tool kits required to make such beautiful things ?

Are there actually competitive *free* alternatives available ? I have been using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), but not able to figure out if it actually possible to make such good designs with it.

---

Edit:

I am really interested in the minimalistic ones. eg :

[image] [source](http://dribbble.com/shots/543645-UX-iOS-UI-iPhone-idea-with-video-process)

[image] [source](http://www.behance.net/gallery/MINIMETEO-for-iPad/4146415)

[image] [source](http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/41613/screenshots/906025/icon.jpg)

[other examples](http://dribbble.com/search?q=fold%20ui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a huge variety of work on Dribbble and Behance so the only way to answer this is with a short directory of other more focussed questions....

- Most of the designs on Dribbble are UI designs, for that, see [**What software is best for GUI design?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/what-software-is-best-for-gui-design)

  - TLDR: usually personal preference between Photoshop and Fireworks; InDesign can be good for info architecture
- If cost is an issue, see also [**Lower-cost alternative to Photoshop**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/lower-cost-alternative-to-photoshop) and [**Is photoshop elements good enough for typical website mockups?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15866/is-photoshop-elements-good-enough-for-typical-website-mockups).

  - TLDR: Photoshop Elements is a worthy lower cost alternative; also consider GIMP, Pixelmator and if your needs are very simple, web-based stuff.
- Behance often features digital painting; for that, see [**Which tools for digital art & paintings**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/which-tools-for-digital-art-paintings).

  - TLDR: Photoshop/Elements is good for this too, but if you prefer something more like traditional painting, consider Autodesk Sketchbook or ArtRage.
- For a general overview of standard design software, see [**What are the different applications in Adobe Creative Suite for?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-are-the-different-applications-in-adobe-creative-suite-for?rq=1)

  - If you don't know the difference between Photoshop, Indesign and Illustrator (and the other stuff in Adobe CS), start here.